# Spearman correlation and splitting 1 variable

Tags: r

```
       Year.Sales.Advertise.Employees
1               1985 1.05 162 32 
2               1986 1.26 285 47 
3               1987 1.47 540 23 
4               1988 2.16 261 68 
5               1989 1.95 360 32 
6                1990 2.4 690 17 
7               1991 2.37 495 58 
8               1992 3.15 948 75 
9               1993 3.57 720 98 
10             1994 4.41 1.14 43 
11             1995 4.5 1.395 76 
12             1996 5.61 1.56 89 
13            1997 5.19 1.38 108 
14             1998 5.67 1.26 76 
15             1999 5.16 1.71 65 
16              2000 6.84 1.86 93
```

I want to find the Spearman correlation between Sales and Advertise and ive been stuck for 3 hours please help. I think I have to separate the 1 variable into 5 variables but Im struggling.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate the 1 variable into 5 variables"?

Comment: What happened that your data is in this format? Are you trying to read a tab-delimited file or something but doing it wrong? If this is how you're getting your data, might be better to start debugging upstream of getting correlations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split our data, i.e.

```
new_df <- setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(df2$Year.Sales.Advertise.Employees, ' '))), 
                   strsplit(names(df2), '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]])
```

which gives,

> ```
>    Year Sales Advertise Employees
> 1  1985  1.05       162        32
> 2  1986  1.26       285        47
> 3  1987  1.47       540        23
> 4  1988  2.16       261        68
> 5  1989  1.95       360        32
> 6  1990   2.4       690        17
> 7  1991  2.37       495        58
> 8  1992  3.15       948        75
> 9  1993  3.57       720        98
> 10 1994  4.41      1.14        43
> 11 1995   4.5     1.395        76
> 12 1996  5.61      1.56        89
> 13 1997  5.19      1.38       108
> 14 1998  5.67      1.26        76
> 15 1999  5.16      1.71        65
> 16 2000  6.84      1.86        93
> ```

You can then use `cor` (i.e. `cor(new_df$Advertise, new_df$Employees)`) to find correlations between any columns you want.

*NOTE1:* Make sure that your initial column is a character (not factor)

*NOTE2:* By default, `cor` function calculates the pearson correlation. For spearman, add the argument `cor(..., method = "spearman")`, as mentioned by @Base_R_Best_R.

**DATA**

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(Year.Sales.Advertise.Employees = c("1985 1.05 162 32", 
"1986 1.26 285 47", "1987 1.47 540 23", "1988 2.16 261 68", "1989 1.95 360 32", 
"1990 2.4 690 17", "1991 2.37 495 58", "1992 3.15 948 75", "1993 3.57 720 98", 
"1994 4.41 1.14 43", "1995 4.5 1.395 76", "1996 5.61 1.56 89", 
"1997 5.19 1.38 108", "1998 5.67 1.26 76", "1999 5.16 1.71 65", 
"2000 6.84 1.86 93")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for something like below or other things

```
# split strings into separate columns
df <- `names<-`(data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,split = " ")))))),
          unlist(strsplit(names(df),split = "\\.")))

# calculate correction coefficient
r <- cor(df$Sales,df$Advertise)
```

such that

```
> r
[1] -0.5624524
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Year.Sales.Advertise.Employees = c("1985 1.05 162 32", 
"1986 1.26 285 47", "1987 1.47 540 23", "1988 2.16 261 68", "1989 1.95 360 32", 
"1990 2.4 690 17", "1991 2.37 495 58", "1992 3.15 948 75", "1993 3.57 720 98", 
"1994 4.41 1.14 43", "1995 4.5 1.395 76", "1996 5.61 1.56 89", 
"1997 5.19 1.38 108", "1998 5.67 1.26 76", "1999 5.16 1.71 65", 
"2000 6.84 1.86 93")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

> df
   Year.Sales.Advertise.Employees
1                1985 1.05 162 32
2                1986 1.26 285 47
3                1987 1.47 540 23
4                1988 2.16 261 68
5                1989 1.95 360 32
6                 1990 2.4 690 17
7                1991 2.37 495 58
8                1992 3.15 948 75
9                1993 3.57 720 98
10              1994 4.41 1.14 43
11              1995 4.5 1.395 76
12              1996 5.61 1.56 89
13             1997 5.19 1.38 108
14              1998 5.67 1.26 76
15              1999 5.16 1.71 65
16              2000 6.84 1.86 93
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly but with my data it shows an error: supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'. I think it's because year sales etc. are all in 1 variable and need to be split and I don't know how to :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for the data to be split into 4 discrete columns, this should do it.

Your data in the question needed some cleaning.  It probably needs more (manual) cleaning, as advertise falls from 720 to 1.14 between 1993 and 1994.  That's likely from hundreds of thousands to millions.

```
x <- c("1985 1.05 162 32",
  "1986 1.26 285 47",
  "1987 1.47 540 23",
  "1988 2.16 261 68",
  "1989 1.95 360 32",
  "1990 2.4 690 17",
  "1991 2.37 495 58",
  "1992 3.15 948 75",
  "1993 3.57 720 98",
  "1994 4.41 1.14 43",
  "1995 4.5 1.395 76",
  "1996 5.61 1.56 89",
  "1997 5.19 1.38 108",
  "1998 5.67 1.26 76",
  "1999 5.16 1.71 65",
  "2000 6.84 1.86 93")

library(tidyverse)
clean_df <- x %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  separate('.',
           into = c('year','sales', 'advertise', 'empl'), 
           sep = ' ') %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric)

cor(clean_df$sales, clean_df$advertise, method = 'spearman')
```